# Jquery unwrap() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

There is a great method in jquery called `wrap()` that will wrap a selected element inside a new element, like so:

Start with:

```
 <p>I wish I was wrapped!</p>
```

Add code:

```
 $("p").wrap("<div></div>");
```

End with:

```
<div><p>I wish I was wrapped!</p></div>
```

But what I need is something that will unwrap, so that the above process is reversed. It seems that the issue is that when you select a bad item (let's say an unnecessary table) that it always grabs what is inside it as well, so if I want to remove all `<td>`s, I am left with nothing, since that removed the `td` and anything inside.

Is there a standard reliable way of removing elements but leaving any children/ancestors alone?

Comment: Check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491991/how-to-unwrap-tags/1492057#1492057) if you want more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JQuery 1.4 unwrap() was added:
http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm checking out all of the other features that slipped under my radar in 1.4.

Comment: @Anthony: This really should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search reveals that there is such functionality, in the form of a small 576 byte plugin called [jqueryunwrap](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryunwrap/). I have not tried it personally, but it is worth a shot. ;)

Comment: I figured there would be plugins. I was hoping for something a bit more reliable/standardized. Good find though.

Answer (score 0):

`$("p").unwrap()` will unwrap the wrapping div....................I hope this helps